Let $K$ be a field. Lie algebra $n,h,g$ over $K$ satisfy exact row $0\to n\to g\to h\to 0$. Show that $K\otimes_{Un} Ug\cong Uh$ as right $g$-modules.
Let $K$ be a field. Lie algebra $n,h,g$ over $K$ satisfy exact row $0\to n\to g\to h\to 0$. Show that $K\otimes_{U n} Ug\cong U h$ as right g-modules.
I just read GTM-4. The question appears on page 233. $K\otimes_{U n}Ug $ seems like $Ug/Un$?I don’t known whether my understanding is right and I’m really not good at tensor product. I will appreciate it if someone could give me the solution. Some viewpoint on how to understand the module constructed by tensor product is also welcomed.

Let
$$0\to n\xrightarrow{i} g\xrightarrow{p} h\to 0$$
$K\otimes U_g$ becomes a $g$-module via $x.(1\otimes x_1x_2\cdots x_k)=1\otimes xx_1x_2\cdots x_k$,and $Uh$ becomes a $g$-module via $x. y_1y_2\cdots y_l=p(x)y_1y_2y_l$. where $x$ is an element of $g$.
Define $\phi: K\otimes U_g \to Uh$ as $\phi(1\otimes x_1x_2\cdots x_k)=p(x_1)p(x_2)\cdots p(x_k)$.It is also a module homomorphism, for $$\begin{aligned}\phi(x.1\otimes x_1x_2\cdots x_k)&=\phi(1\otimes xx_1x_2\cdots x_k)\\&=p(x)p(x_1)\cdots p(x_k)\\&=x.p(x_1)p(x_2)\cdots p(x_k)\\&=x.\phi(x_1x_2\cdots x_k)\end{aligned}$$
$\phi$ is epimorphism because $p$ is epimorphism. It suffices to show that $\ker \phi=0$. Suppose $\phi(1\otimes x_1 x_2\cdots x_k)=0$, then $p(x_1)=p(x_2)=\cdots=p(x_k)=0$, which means $x_i\in \operatorname{Im} n,i=1,2\cdots,k$.Therefore, $1\otimes x_1 x_2\cdots x_k=x_1x_2\cdots x_k. 1\otimes 1=0\otimes 1=0$.(Lie algebra element $x$ trivially act on $v$ via $x.v=0$)
